# Sheet numbers do not change when I fill.

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a formula:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet11!$K$3:$K$200,B$66,Sheet11!$O$3:$O$200)
```

I want to fill cells below it and have the sheet number adjust, like this:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet12!$K$3:$K$200,B$66,Sheet12!$O$3:$O$200)
=SUMIF(Sheet13!$K$3:$K$200,B$66,Sheet13!$O$3:$O$200)
```

and so on. I tried the ROW function and INDIRECT, but I must not be putting them in the right order as I do not get the result intended.

Answer (score 0):

The sheet number isn't something that auto-adjusts because there's no logic to indicate it should be a different sheet.  You could create the range reference using INDIRECT to adjust the sheet name.  Here's the gist, but you will need to adjust it based on your cell locations.

Say your first formula goes in row 1, so the sheet number would be `ROW()+10`.  Instead of:

```
             Sheet11!$K$3:$K$200,      use:

INDIRECT("Sheet"& ROW()+10 & "!$K$3:$K$200")
```